# CSS DIV overlay with non-working overflow/height

Tags: html, css, overflow, overlay

This should be easy, but I don't know why it's not working. 
I have a `div` overlay that pops up when clicking an image and my goal is to have the content on the top portion and have it scroll and have a close button on the bottom. However, it is not scrolling, the height is not accurate, and the close button is not positioned correctly. Here is the code:

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
#popup {
    display:none;
    position:relative;     
    left:25px;
    top:45%;         
    width:275px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-70px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background:#000000;
    border:10px solid #000;
    border-radius:20px;
    z-index:100000;      
}
#alt {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    overflow:auto;
    height:175px;
}
#closebtn {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:25px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("popupalert").onclick = function() {
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        popup.style.display = "block";
    };
    document.getElementById("closebtn").onclick = function() {
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        popup.style.display = "none";      
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/mlogo2x_3.png" width="100%" id="popupalert">
<div id="popup" align="center">
    <div id="alt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales tempor orci non convallis. Curabitur vestibulum, est ac placerat dictum, leo arcu congue lectus, sed dictum eros dolor vel dui. Sed molestie mollis tortor vitae lacinia. Donec aliquam dolor porta, tristique libero a, malesuada metus. Nullam id venenatis elit. Duis eu mi vel tortor ullamcorper luctus. Nunc ornare maximus justo id consectetur.<br><br></div>
    <div id="closebtn" style="font-size:24pt">✕</div>
</div>
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juyunx70/2/).

Comment: Have you tried using a plugin. I use fancybox a bunch for stuff like this http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: I have not because I'm trying to keep the code as simple as possible. This code is the entirety of the "website:" an image with a popup when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `overflow: auto` for `#popop`

Comment: My reply to Nasser actually applies here also so I will paste it for convenience: This would be fine, however I only want `#alt` to scroll. I want to always see the close X button in `#closebtn` at the bottom, which currently isn't even positioning correctly. Essentially, I want it to look like [**this**](http://i.imgur.com/LVwDMAe.png) (but an X instead of a question mark, you can ignore that).